# Uso del suffisso -oide

Tags: word-usage

**-oide:**

> [dal greco -oeidḗs, da êidos, forma]. Ultimo elemento di parole composte derivate dal greco o formate modernamente, che ha il significato di “simile a, affine a”:
>
> - usato come suffisso di molti termini del linguaggio scientifico e sta a indicare una somiglianza, una relazione, una affinità con il concetto o la cosa espressa dalla parola a cui viene aggiunto (per esempio: sferoide, metalloide).
> - In medicina e in psichiatria è usato per indicare una sintomatologia meno grave, uno stato morboso la cui tipicità è solo apparente (per esempio: paranoide, mongoloide).

Perché  quando viene usato nel linguaggio comune gli aggettivi spesso assumono una connotazione negativa? Come ad esempio, umanoide, genialoide, sinistroide, intellettualoide etc.

Comment: Bella domanda! Do qui una parziale risposta che metto come commento, sperando che qualcuno possa darne una più completa. Il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/oide/) (al punto 2.) assimila questo uso a quello patologico e psichiatrico; aggiungo che ho l'impressione che abbiano svolto un certo ruolo nel dare al suffisso un connotato negativo in particolare termini come “mongoloide”, “negroide” e simili, in origine “scientifici” (e ti raccomando la scientificità) ma poi entrati nell'uso quasi solo in senso spregiativo.

Comment: Perché è solamente "simile", non è esattamente quello. Un intellettualoide non è un vero intellettuale, gli assomiglia solo; un umanoide è simile a un umano, ma non é umano, ecc.

Answer (score 3):

Concordo con @Roberto. L'aggettivo che descrive un sostantivo ma ha -oide come suffisso, implica imprecisione, inverificabilità o suggerisce una deformazione (vera o presunta) che può solo essere negativa/diminutiva rispetto alla realtà del sostantivo descritto.

Comment: Un paraboloide non ha niente di negativo/diminutivo.

Comment: Un paraboloide non è una parabola; è la superficie che si ottiene ruotando una parabola sul suo asse. Volendo, è una superficie che somiglia a una parabola, ma non lo è, essendo una superficie. Anche qui abbiamo in un certo senso una deformazione, per quanto non esattamente "negativa", se non nel fatto che chiamare un paraboloide una parabola sarebbe tecnicamente scorretto. Altro esempio geometrico: trapezoide. Somiglia a un trapezio ma ha un lato curvo.

Answer (score 2):

Lo stesso fenomeno è avvenuto in spagnolo dalla fine del secolo XIX, come viene spiegato in [questo articolo](https://www.academia.edu/1251096/oide_un_sufijo_cosmopolita) del professor Antonio Rifón dell'Universidade di Vigo, pubblicato nella rivista *Cuadernos del Instituto Historia de la Lengua*. La lettura dell'articolo mi ha fatto capire che questa domanda non ha una facile risposta perché l'apparizione della connotazione negativa nelle parole costrutte col suffisso -oide è ancora un tema di studio tra linguisti.

L'articolo spiega che nel 1856 il suffisso -oide non aveva ancora in spagnolo questa connotazione semantica peggiorativa, ma era usato esclusivamente in derivati di parole colte nell'ambito scientifico. Secondo l'ipotesi dell'autore, l'acquisto di questa connotazione negativa è associata alla scoperta nel XIX secolo di nuove razze umane che vengono chiamate *mongoloide*, *caucasoide*, *europoide*, *negroide*, *australoide* e *laponoide*. Queste parole appaiono prima in inglese con il suffisso "-oid", ma poi vengono incorporate in altre lingue europee. Si trattava in teoria di termini scientifici che non dovrebbero avere nessuna connotazione negativa. Tuttavia, lo studio delle razze non era mai privo di una certa sfumatura spregiativa o diminutiva o dell'idea che queste razze erano ad un gradino inferiore sulla linea evolutiva rispetto alla razza europea. Quando questi vocaboli cominciano a essere conosciuti, si comincia a associare il suffisso -oide a un significato spregiativo o diminutivo.

Comment: Chiaro, è vero che in Spagna la giornata tende ad essere traslata in avanti, nel senso che, p.e., a scuola i ragazzi entrano alle 10 e si cena alle 22?